# my computer wont recognize my SanDisk Ultra Plus 128gb micro sd

Tags: sd-card

my computer, currently running ubuntu 15.10 used to recognize my sd card, i havent changed anything on the computer or sd card and it will not recognize it at all. i have an 8gb card and the computer recognizes that. is there any way to remedy the situation?

Comment: What's the output of `ls /dev/sd*` before and (5 seconds) after you plug in the micro SD card?

Comment: @wb9688 Why not recommend to use `lsblk`?

Comment: @LiveWireBT I didn't know about `lsblk`